# getting error: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier ',' in

Tags: php, preg-match, ereg

Here is the syntax I am trying to use to replace PHP5.3 problematic "if (ereg".

origianl code:

```
if (ereg('([0-9.-]{1,}),([0-9.-]{1,})', $location, $regs))
```

new code:

```
if (preg_match('/[0-9.-]{1,}/,/[0-9.-]{1,}/', $location, $regs))
```

this new code is causing the warning.
I tried to figure it out using previous posts, here, but I am not quite getting it right.

Thanks.

Comment: Why did you replace the `()` with `/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to escape your slashes which are your regex delimiters:

```
if (preg_match('/[0-9.-]{1,}/,/[0-9.-]{1,}/', $location, $regs))
```

should be

```
if (preg_match('/[0-9.-]{1,}\/,\/[0-9.-]{1,}/', $location, $regs))
```

Comment: @Jim: I'm not very familiar with `ereg`, but `\/` tries to match `/` literally which you don't seem to be doing in your original expression. Are you sure that is what you want?